Can I define a proxy exception on the SUSE SLES15 media command line?
We have a specific intranet configuration where I need to specify a proxy to reach the SUSE update servers for SLES (e.g. for the installer update), but we also have a local update server that must be contacted directly.
So the problem is: If I specify proxy=http://IP:port, then all traffic will be directed to the proxy; that is http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables will be set to the corresponding value.
To avoid using the proxy I typically use environment variable no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,.our.domain.org.
So the question is:
Is there a GRUB boot command-line parameter that causes no_proxy (NO_PROXY in /etc/sysconfig/proxy) to be set (when booting the SLES15 installation medium for installation or upgrade)?

It's hard to prove a negative, but I don't think you can. The number of supported boot options is quite limited and no_proxy doesn't appear to be one. For example the manual only mentions  an option to specify a proxy when you need one https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP6/html/SLES-all/cha-boot-parameters.html#sec-boot-parameters-advanced-proxy

One work-around is to simply install the system and apply updates immediately after the first boot, once your system can run more sophisticated tooling (that does honour no_proxy settings) than the installer ; another is to use a proxy server that can reach both your internal and internet resources (and take the potential delay when accessing internal resources not directly as a compromise)

@HBruijn Unfortunately the proxy is managed by another team, and the setup is quite complex.
